# Print table with Angular md-card and md-color

Tags: javascript, angularjs, printing

Hello I am trying to print a table that is populated with data in a md-card. The back ground is set using md-color theme picker (https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.0/demo/colors). My issue is that when pulling the outer html to print, the md-card and md-color do not show in the table. the table shows only data and no design. I got my sample from here (https://codepen.io/mil/pen/WRyzLa?editors=0010) Any help will be great thank you in advance!!

Code:

```
<table align="center" id="print-section">
            <tr ng-repeat="student in class">
                <td>
                    <md-card class="student-badge" md-colors="{background: '{{primary}}-500'}">
                        <md-card-title class="student-badge-title">
                            <md-card-title-text>
                                <span class="student-name">{{student.name}}</span>
                            </md-card-title-text>
                        </md-card-title>
                        <md-card-content>
                            <span class="badge" id="student-info">{{student.id}}</span>
                        </md-card-content>
                    </md-card>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Javascript:

```
$scope.print = function() {
        var contents = document.getElementById("print-section").outerHTML;
        console.log("print " + contents);
        var frame1 = document.createElement('iframe');
            frame1.name = "frame3";
            frame1.style.position = "absolute";
            frame1.style.top = "-1000000px";
            document.body.appendChild(frame1);
            var frameDoc = frame1.contentWindow ? frame1.contentWindow : frame1.contentDocument.document ? frame1.contentDocument.document : frame1.contentDocument;
            frameDoc.document.open();
            frameDoc.document.write('<html><head><style>All styles and angular dependencies are added here</script></style>');
            frameDoc.document.write('</head><body>');
            frameDoc.document.write(contents);
            frameDoc.document.write('</body></html>');
            frameDoc.document.close();
            setTimeout(function () {
              window.frames["frame3"].focus();
              window.frames["frame3"].print();
              document.body.removeChild(frame1);
          }, 500);
          return false;
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the issue, when creating the new page with angular make sure all your dependencies are included in the Framedoc.document.write and make sure no syntax errors are happening. This was in my case the issue I had everything however I was missing an html tag! Hope this helps to anybody with similar issues!